# Erase/Select all contiguous shapes smaller than a certain number of pixels in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a layer in Photoshop of star trails, but just the trails themselves. Every pixel in the layer, for now, is white. Around the pixels there are also stray pixels of white that are a result of noise from the image that was toned similar to the stars. Is there a way that I can select and erase these stray pixels? Perhaps by selecting all contiguous shapes smaller than 10 pixels?